# Access to Android Settings.Secure from C++

Tags: android, c++, security, android-ndk, android-security

### Introduction

I am using Android NDK in my project to improve security. I want to get the unique identifier of the Android device.

### Notes

1. **Important**: I don't want to use JNI, I want to access settings from native code.
2. As far as I know, `Settings.Secure` gets settings using this path: `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`

### Question

How can I get the unique identifier of an Android device using C++ code, without JNI calls?

Comment: If apps could bypass permission requirement simply by accessing sensitive system data from native code, there wouldn't be much point in having a permission model at all. So you would need some way of asking for permission to access that data, which would involve JNI. Also I'm not sure what you mean by _"using Android NDK in my project to improve security"_. There's nothing inherently more secure about native code. The reasons for using native code is mainly performance and/or to make use of shared/legacy native code that you don't want to reimplement.

Comment: @Michael, for example, storing sensitive data (e.g. API keys) using C++ code make it more difficult to find them during the disassembling process.